# Codeigniter unlink not work when update file pdf

Tags: codeigniter-3

> I want to update file pdf but function unlink not work

- this my unlink : @unlink(FCPATH .'./assets/file_master/'.$_FILES['nama_file']['name']);

- this my controller

```
public function update_action() 
    {
    $tahun_dokumen_last = $this->Tb_master_model->get_by_id($this->input->post('id_master', true))->tahun_dokumen;
    if($this->input->post('tahun_dokumen',TRUE)=="" || $this->input->post('tahun_dokumen',TRUE)==NULL){
            $tahun_dokumen = $tahun_dokumen_last;
        }else{
            $tahun_dokumen = $this->input->post('tahun_dokumen',TRUE);
        }      
        if($_FILES['nama_file']['name']==""){
        $filename = $this->Tb_master_model->get_by_id($this->input->post('id_master', true))->nama_file;
        }else{
            //@unlink('./assets/file_master/'.$_FILES['nama_file']['name']);
            @unlink(FCPATH .'./assets/file_master/'.$_FILES['nama_file']['name']);

            $filename = $_FILES['nama_file']['name'];
            $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename);
        } 
        $file = $_FILES['nama_file'];
        $this->_rules();
        $maks_size                =  25000000;//25MB
        $config['upload_path']   = './assets/file_master/'; //kalo path salah maka ggal upload
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|rar|zip';
        $config['max_size']      = $maks_size;
        $config['overwrite']     = TRUE;
        $config['file_name']     = $filename;
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
```

> help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want delete old file use file name from database and unlink, not with $_FILES['nama_file']['name']

```
$filename = $this->Tb_master_model->get_by_id($this->input->post('id_master', true))->nama_file;
@unlink(FCPATH .'./assets/file_master/'.$filename);
```